# SQL query to determine if one table has more rows with an attribute than another

Tags: postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble with a homework exercise as follows:

> Find all departments with more professors than students.

The tables involved are as follows:

```
            Table "university.prof"
  Column   |         Type          | Modifiers
-----------+-----------------------+-----------
 pnum      | character(9)          | not null
 lastname  | character varying(12) | not null
 firstname | character varying(12) |
 dept      | character(4)          |
 office    | character(6)          |
 rank      | character(1)          |
 date_emp  | date                  | not null
 salary    | numeric(8,2)          |
 manager   | character(9)          |
Indexes:
    "prof_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (pnum)

      Table "university.student"
  Column   |     Type      | Modifiers
-----------+---------------+-----------
 snum      | character(9)  | not null
 lastname  | character(12) |
 firstname | character(12) |
 dept      | character(4)  |
 date_ent  | date          |
 cr_comp   | smallint      |
 gpa       | numeric(4,3)  |
 advisor   | character(9)  |
Indexes:
    "student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (snum)
```

The question essentially asks for a list of values where the left table has more rows with the value than the right table.  How do I do this?  This query doesn't work:

```
SET search_path TO university;

SELECT dept
FROM prof
GROUP BY dept
HAVING count(*) > (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM student
    GROUP BY dept
);
```

resulting in the following error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This code doesn't work, either, resulting in no rows returned (the correct answer returns two rows):

```
SET search_path TO university;

SELECT prof.dept
FROM prof, student
GROUP BY prof.dept
HAVING count(prof.*) > count(student.*);
```

How am I supposed to do this?  I'm not looking for a full answer, but hints on how to structure the query.  I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on Windows 7.

**Edit:**  Thanks for your help.  The correct answer is as follows:

```
SET search_path TO university;

SELECT prof.dept
FROM prof, student
WHERE prof.dept = student.dept
GROUP BY prof.dept
HAVING count(DISTINCT prof.*) > count(DISTINCT student.*);
```

**Edit 2:**  There is a better solution.  I have accepted the answer containing this solution.

Comment: Use of `HAVING count(*) > (` is the most possible cause of error.

Comment: Second attempt misses a join predicate that connects two tables by department - **where prof.dept = student.dept** and keyword **distinct** in both counts because this way it counts repetitions of professors and students and it is always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Find all departments with more professors than students.

Consider this one:

```
SELECT p.dept, p.prof_ct, s.stud_ct
FROM (
   SELECT dept, count(*) AS prof_ct
   FROM   university.prof
   GROUP  BY dept
   ) p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT dept, count(*) AS stud_ct
   FROM   university.student
   GROUP  BY dept
   ) s USING (dept)
WHERE p.prof_ct >= s.stud_ct OR s.stud_ct IS NULL
ORDER BY p.dept;
```

Should be **much faster** than your present solution, because students and professors are counted before fewer (by orders of magnitude) joins by `dept` are made.

It also observes the case where a department has **no students**, which your solution misses presently. Your cross join eliminates all departments without students (or professors).

Answer (score 0):

Part of Your First Query which is causing error:

```
SELECT dept
FROM prof
GROUP BY dept
HAVING count(*) > (
    SELECT count(*) /* This subquery would yield rows equal to no of different  
    FROM student        Department to which students belong.
    GROUP BY dept       Thus you can't compare it with > symbol.*/      
);
```

Instead you must iterate through the `professor` table (*which select does*) and for each professor calculate the no of professors in that department and then correspondingly find the students which belong to the same department as that of above professor.
Something like this:

```
select t.prof from prof t where
(
select count(*) from prof where dept=t.dept
)
>
(
select count(*) from student where dept=t.dept
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution uses views:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW p AS (
    SELECT dept, count(*) num
    FROM prof
    GROUP BY dept
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW s AS (
    SELECT dept, count(*) num
    FROM student
    GROUP BY dept
);
SELECT DISTINCT p.dept
FROM p, s
WHERE p.num > s.num;
```

This code correctly handles the case where there are no professors or students for a given department.